# 14.04. Unity gone. Tried everything in the forums. Nothing will bring it back

Tags: unity

I tried enabling the cube desktop in compiz and unity vanished. No reboots will bring it back. I tried reinstalling ubuntu desktop and that did nothing. I tried resetting compiz to defaults and enabling the unity plugin and that did nothing either. I've basically tried everything in every answer and they haven't done a thing. So let me know what information I need to give you and I'll type it out here. This happened ten minutes after updating from 12.04-14.04.

I do get an error "plugin opengl not loaded."

Comment: Is unity running okay under a guest account?

Comment: @Parto yes. I went ahead and made another admin account and transferred my files. Inelegant fix but it's better than reinstalling. Thanks for your comment, it helped a lot.

Comment: That meant the issue was in your local config files not in the global configs. Inelegant fix but a fix all the same.

Comment: @Parto how does one fix the local config files? Tried resetting everything to no avail. I ask this for future readers, potentially.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Virtual Console via CTRL + ALT + F1
2. Reinstall unity , ubuntu desktop and lightdm using the command line below

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop lighdm
   ```
3. Check your unity by re-run it.

   ```
   unity
   ```

   read the error line shown on the console 
   If it match the Error message shown blow , Go To Step 4. otherwise (if no Error log   displayed) ,re-install your driver and reboot your device .

   ```
   Error : plugin "opengl" could not be loaded
   ```
4. restore xorg.conf files amd reset plugins

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.XXXXXXXX /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf

   export DISPLAY=:0

   gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
   ```
5. reboot your PC

Comment: The line from the step 4 with /etc/X11/xorg.conf.XXXXXXXX didn't work for me, but "gsettings reset ..." saved the day!

Comment: There is a type in the first line. Change `lighdm` to `lightdm`

Answer (score 1):

Run `ccsm` from a terminal. If you can't open a terminal do the following:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in and then:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
```

After it opens re-enable Unity Plugin (from Desktop category) and OpenGL plugin (from General category).

Comment: OpenGL is enabled. I tried disabling and re-enabling. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

Comment: Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

as described on [WEB UPD8 post](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html)

Seb